# Regex captures one instance of the pattern but not the other. How to fix this?

Tags: python, regex, text

I have this piece of text:

> W/NNP Yes/NNP Get/NNP Paid/NNP for/IN Going/NNP to/TO College/NNP !/.
>   Check/NNP it/PRP out/RP here/RB !/. http/NN :/:
>   //sldollar.notlong.com/JJ apple/NN iphone/NN TGIF/NNP swine/NN flu/NN

I am currently using this regex to capture some regions of interest:

```
[a-zA-Z]*/NN[PS]* [a-zA-Z]*/NN[PS]*
```

I am using [RegexPal](http://www.regexpal.com) to test this.

[image]

This captures `TGIF/NNP swine/NN` but not `swine/NN flu/NN`. Any suggestions on how to fix my regex to capture this?

Comment: The reason is that some matches overlap.

Comment: @Maulwurfn: Yeap. Thank you. Just realized this can be solved using positive lookahead and posted my answer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3027718/overlapping-matches-with-finditer-in-python

Comment: @tripleee: Well something like that, just that I'm not tacking spam though ;)

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else needs this, I guess the answer is to use a positive lookahead:

```
([a-zA-Z]*/NN[PS]* )(?=([a-zA-Z]*/NN[PS]*))
```

Answer (score 1):

Multiple matches cannot overlap.

```
apple/NN iphone/NN TGIF/NNP swine/NN flu/NN
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
         CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC DDDDDDDDDDDDDDD
```

Matches marked A and B above follow each other, but because piece C starts in the middle of match A (and likewise for D within B), they are not matches.

You need to match once and then re-search at some point after the previous starting point, or use lookahead so the latter part isn't consumed.