# Regex code not working in python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.4

```
import re
st=input()  #The input string
ss=input()  #The substring to be searched
lss=len(ss)
lst=len(st)
x=lst-lss
for i in range(x):
    r=re.search(r'(%s)'%ss,st,i)
    if r:
        print(r.start(),r.end())
```

Above is code is response to a task. The task is:

A string S is given.

I need to find the indices of the start and end of string k in S.

If the input is:

```
aaadaa
aa
```

Output should be:

```
(0, 1)  
(1, 2)
(4, 5)
```

I know the code which i have written is wrong because i am not getting the desired output.I went through and through again the line after for loop. I am not able to convince myself that it is wrong.I just want to know why the code after the for loop does not work?
Can someone help me through?

Comment: I don't think you're supposed to pass `i` to `search` like that. the third argument to search is `flags`, not "index to start searching from", if that's what you're trying to do.

Comment: You don't even need regex for this (and it's an overkill). Use standard `string.find()`.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the [`re.search()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/re.html#re.search)'s document first, its third parameter is `flag`.

---

In your case, you are looking for **overlapping** results, I realized there is no straight forward solutions, so I wrote a recursion

```
import re
string = input()  # The input string
pattern = input()  # The substring to be searched

def match(pattern, string, startIdx=0):
    if startIdx <= len(string) - len(pattern):
        res = re.search(pattern, string[startIdx:])
        if res is not None:
            print(res.start() + startIdx, res.end() + startIdx - 1)
            return match(pattern, string, startIdx + res.start() + 1)


match(pattern, string)
```

whose output is

```
0 1
1 2
4 5
```

which should do the work as you've expected.

---

I checked preexisted solutions, they does not fits your request:

- `re.finditer` can only do **non-overlapping** search.
- `re.findall` do **overlapping** search, but fails to retrieve the index.
- `re.finditer` and `re.findall` with [look ahead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3027785/1487532) returns matched text only.

I guess writing this own function is the best way to do it.

---

Good question, though.